# SHA-2 with TLS below 1.1 or lower

Tags: ssl-certificate, tls

I have a call to a 3rd party webservice that uses HTTPs for transport security.

The 3rd party are due to upgrade their certificate to SHA-2, withdrawing SHA-1.  Does my call need to be able to use TLS1.2 to continue connecting, or can TLS1.1 or below interact with SHA-2 certificates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The digital signature of the X.509 certificate has no impact on TLS.  It's the former that is changing from SHA-1 to SHA-256 as part of the SHA-1 deprecation programme.

It is true that TLS has a HMAC within it that use the SHA algorithm and TLS 1.1 does not use SHA-256 for this, but that's completely different to the X.509 certificate with SHA-256 digital signatures which your 3rd party will be upgrading to.